# XML - System.NullPointerException: Attempt to de-reference a null object

Tags: integration, webservices, callout, xml

Following is my XML content :

```
<GeocodeResponse>
    <status>OK</status>
    <result>
        <type>postal_code</type>
        <formatted_address>Mexico city, Mexico, Mexico</formatted_address>
        <address_component>
            <long_name>123456</long_name>
            <short_name>123456</short_name>
            <type>postal_code</type>
        </address_component>
    </result>
</GeocodeResponse>
```

I written the following service to get the details from external system :

```
@RestResource(urlMapping='/ReadXMLfromExternalSystem/*') 
global class ReadXMLfromExternalSystem {

    @HttpGet
    global static void parseResponseDom(){
        Http h = new Http();
        HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
        req.setEndpoint('http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/xml?address=123456');
        req.setMethod('GET');
        HttpResponse res = h.send(req);
        Dom.Document doc = res.getBodyDocument();

        //Retrieve the root element for this document.
        Dom.XMLNode address = doc.getRootElement();

        // LINE Number 16
        String long_name = address.getChildElement('long_name', null).getText();
        String short_name = address.getChildElement('short_name', null).getText();

        System.debug('Long Name: ' + long_name);
        System.debug('Short Name: ' + short_name);

        for(Dom.XMLNode child : address.getChildElements()) {
            System.debug(child.getText());
        }
    }
}
```

I am getting following error on line No. 16

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your parsing code does not match the format of your XML. The root node of your XML is the `GeocodeResponse`, not the `address_component` that you want the properties from.

You need to transverse the nodes in the document to get down to the level you want.

```
Dom.Document doc = res.getBodyDocument();

Dom.XMLNode GeocodeResponse = doc.getRootElement();
Dom.XMLNode result = GeocodeResponse.getChildElement('result', null);
Dom.XMLNode address_component = result.getChildElement('address_component', null);

String long_name = address_component.getChildElement('long_name', null).getText();
String short_name = address_component.getChildElement('short_name', null).getText();
```

This is covered in the documentation for [Reading and Writing XML Using the DOM](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_xml_dom.htm).

> ## Document Example
>
> For the purposes of the sample below, assume that the `url` argument passed into the `parseResponseDom` method returns this XML response:
>
> ```
> <address>
>     <name>Kirk Stevens</name>
>     <street1>808 State St</street1>
>     <street2>Apt. 2</street2>
>     <city>Palookaville</city>
>     <state>PA</state>
>     <country>USA</country>
> </address>
> ```
>
> The following example illustrates how to use DOM classes to parse the XML response returned in the body of a GET request:
>
> ```
> public class DomDocument {
>
>     // Pass in the URL for the request
>     // For the purposes of this sample,assume that the URL
>     // returns the XML shown above in the response body
>     public void parseResponseDom(String url){
>         Http h = new Http();
>         HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
>         // url that returns the XML in the response body
>         req.setEndpoint(url);
>         req.setMethod('GET');
>         HttpResponse res = h.send(req);
>         Dom.Document doc = res.getBodyDocument();
>
>         //Retrieve the root element for this document.
>         Dom.XMLNode address = doc.getRootElement();
>
>         String name = address.getChildElement('name', null).getText();
>         String state = address.getChildElement('state', null).getText();
>         // print out specific elements
>         System.debug('Name: ' + name);
>         System.debug('State: ' + state);
>
>         // Alternatively, loop through the child elements.
>         // This prints out all the elements of the address
>         for(Dom.XMLNode child : address.getChildElements()) {
>            System.debug(child.getText());
>         }
>     }
> }
> ```

Comment: Actually i am totally newbie for this XML parse. thank you for clear me. Can i use insert call in this salesforce ??

Comment: @NailDavid Yes. Just make sure you bulkify your logic to be on safer side.

Comment: @RohitMourya Okay Thank you very much. i will do it according to my data. :)

Comment: @RohitMourya i have another question regarding this. can you help me here or do i need to post another question ?

Comment: @NailDavid Better to post it as a another question

Comment: @RohitMourya check this post please : https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/191006/not-getting-stored-multiple-results-using-xml-file

Comment: @NailDavid I've posted the answer