# Not getting stored multiple results using xml file

Tags: apex, integration, callout, xml, xmlnode

I have following xml and i am going to insert in one custom object's custom field called `Formatted_address__c`.

Now, Problem is all Formatted address not inserting, it just taking the first address> please see the code and guide me where i am doing wrong code.

XML :

```
<GeocodeResponse>
    <status>OK</status>
    <result>
        <type>route</type>
        <formatted_address>US-123, United States</formatted_address>
    </result>
    <result>
        <type>route</type>
        <formatted_address>VA-123, Virginia, USA</formatted_address>
    </result>
    <result>
        <type>route</type>
        <formatted_address>CT-123, Connecticut, USA</formatted_address>
    </result>
    <result>
        <type>route</type>
        <formatted_address>CA-123, California, USA</formatted_address>
    </result>
</GeocodeResponse>
```

APEX :

```
@RestResource(urlMapping='/ReadXMLfromExternalSystem/*') 
global class ReadXMLfromExternalSystem {

    @HttpGet
    global static void parseResponseDom(){
        Http h = new Http();
        HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
        req.setEndpoint('http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/xml?address=123');
        req.setMethod('GET');
        HttpResponse res = h.send(req);

        Dom.Document doc = res.getBodyDocument();

        Dom.XMLNode GeocodeResponse = doc.getRootElement();
        List<Dom.XmlNode> xrec = GeocodeResponse.getchildelements();
        Dom.XmlNode result = GeocodeResponse.getChildElement('result', null);


        //Insert from external system
        List<XML_Insert__c> xmlinsertList = new List<XML_Insert__c>();
        for(Dom.XMLNode child : xrec){
                String formatted_address = result.getChildElement('formatted_address', null).getText();
                XML_Insert__c xmlinsert = new XML_Insert__c();
                xmlinsert.Formatted_address__c = formatted_address;
                xmlinsertList.add(xmlinsert);
        }
        if(xmlinsertList.size() > 0){
            insert xmlinsertList;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were very near to get address field. You just needed to add check for `formatted_address` node. Refer below code:

```
Dom.XMLNode GeocodeResponse = doc.getRootElement();
List<Dom.XmlNode> xrec = GeocodeResponse.getChildelements();
List<XML_Insert__c> xmlinsertList = new List<XML_Insert__c>();
for(Dom.XMLNode child : xrec){
    List<Dom.XMLNode> resultList = child.getChildElements();
    System.debug('resultList::'+resultList.size());

    for(Dom.XMLNode result: resultList) {
        if(result.getName() == 'formatted_address') {
            String formatted_address = result.getText();
            System.debug('formatted_address::'+formatted_address);
            XML_Insert__c xmlinsert = new XML_Insert__c();
            xmlinsert.Formatted_address__c = formatted_address;
            xmlinsertList.add(xmlinsert);
        }
    }
}
if(xmlinsertList.size() > 0){
    insert xmlinsertList;
}
```

Comment: Thank you :) Can you please tell me when we have to use getChildren() in this case ??

Comment: @NailDavid Part 1: It's really simple. Try to visualize your XML as a JSON. If your root node contains multiple child nodes like this e.g. `<name>ABC</name>` then consider it as a single property because it doesn't has any child nodes. And if node has something like this`<address> <Street>1</Street><Pincode><123456</Pincode></address>` then it is a object (if you compare it with JSON format `address = {Stree:1,Pincode:123456}`)

Comment: @NailDavid Part 2: and lastly if you've xml something like this : `<address> <Street>1</Street><Pincode><123456</Pincode></address> <address> <Street>1</Street><Pincode><123456</Pincode></address> <address> <Street>1</Street><Pincode><123456</Pincode></address>`. Then consider it as an array of objects where `address` is a object. If you've singular entity then use `getChildElement()` else use `getChildElements()`. Hope it helps

Answer (score 1):

```
@RestResource(urlMapping='/ReadXMLfromExternalSystem/*') 
global class ReadXMLfromExternalSystem {

    @HttpGet
    global static void parseResponseDom(){
        Http h = new Http();
        HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
        req.setEndpoint('http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/xml?address=123');
        req.setMethod('GET');
        HttpResponse res = h.send(req);

        Dom.Document doc = res.getBodyDocument();

        Dom.XMLNode GeocodeResponse = doc.getRootElement();
        List<Dom.XmlNode> xrec = GeocodeResponse.getchildelements();
        Dom.XmlNode result = GeocodeResponse.getChildElement('result', null);

        system.debug('getting zxml data===>'+xrec);
        //Insert from external system
        List<XML_Insert__c> xmlinsertList = new List<XML_Insert__c>();
        Integer count = 0;
        XML_Insert__c xmlinsert;
        for(Dom.XMLNode child : xrec)
        {
                if(child.getNodeType() == DOM.XMLNodeType.ELEMENT)
                {
                    system.debug('entering here==>'+child.getName());
                    if(child.getName() == 'result')
                    {
                        system.debug('entered after result');
                        List<DOM.XMLNode> inner2 = child.getChildElements();
                        system.debug('inner222===>'+inner2);
                        for(Dom.XMLNode nodess : inner2)
                        {
                            system.debug('entered second for loop'+nodess);
                            if(nodess.getNodeType() == DOM.XMLNodeType.ELEMENT)
                            {
                                system.debug('node names===>'+nodess.getName());
                                if(nodess.getName() == 'formatted_address')
                                {
                                    xmlinsert = new XML_Insert__c();
                                    xmlinsert.Formatted_address__c = nodess.getText();
                                    xmlinsertList.add(xmlinsert);
                                    system.debug('entered formatted address==>'+nodess.getText());
                                }
                            }
                        }

                    }


                }

                count++;
        }
        system.debug('count are===>'+count);
        if(xmlinsertList.size() > 0){
            insert xmlinsertList;
        }
    }
}
```